# Request error 401

Tags: c#

I very bad know English and so i can`t search answer in Google.

So... This is my code

```
             HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=" + textBox2.Text + "&password=" + textBox1.Text);
             HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
             StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
             string auth_id = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

this is code to get token (in Russian Social Network Vk.com =)) And when username and password  are good, all good. But when  username and password are bade. I have error 401.

Comment: you know that jamming the username and password on the URL isn't going to protect them, even when you're using https?

Comment: And the problem / question is…?

Comment: I have error 401. why? how i can kill this problem

Comment: If you don't pass in the correct credentials, the server will return error 401.  There is nothing for you to fix.

Comment: but why ? I need to fix. How users be use my program ?

Comment: You understand why you need to pass correct credentials, and how the server indicates that you have failed to do so, right?  Then can you be clearer about what you need help with?  Is it prompting the users for their credentials?  What is it you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

401 means `Unauthorized` and is likely what that service uses to tell you that the username and password are wrong. I expect that it's normal behaviour for that OAUTH service.

Comment: and how i can make that program will not stop ?

Comment: Handle/catch the 401 and process it as "bad credentials" to your user.

Comment: i don`t know how do this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i make this but i have 401.